# Matlab: diff(interp1(...'pchip')) produces strange results?

Tags: matlab, numeric, numerical-methods, numerical, differentiation

I have the following arbitrary data:

```
t=[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 14];
C=[0 1 5 8 10 8 6 4 3.0 2.2 1.5 0.6 0];
area=trapz(t,C);
E=C./area;
F=cumtrapz(t,E);
```

When plotted, it looks as follows:
[image]

Now, I want to smoothen the plots:

```
t_int=[];
E_int=[];
F_int=[];

xmin=min(t);
xmax=max(t);
points=5000;
stepSize=(xmax-xmin)/points;

for i=xmin:stepSize:xmax
    t_int=[t_int i];
    E_int=[E_int interp1(t, E, i,'pchip')];
    F_int=[F_int interp1(t, F, i,'pchip')];
end
```

[image]

Okay, so here we get to the actual part where the problem is.
In reality, I have some F plot and I would like to get its corresponding E plot.
Since the F plot is the integral of E, E is the differentiated F plot.

So then:

```
dy=diff(F_int);
dx=diff(t_int);
dydx = dy./dx;
plot(t_int(:,1:length(dydx)),dydx,t_int,E_int)
legend('E (calculated)','E (actual)')
```

[image]

**Why is the calculated E plot so wonky?**

Comment: Because of the interpolation, of course.

Comment: Yes, it is caused by the interpolation. But since the interpolated graph is smooth, why isn't the diff() output smooth as well?

Comment: Because....Its the derivative of the interpolation graph... if you zoom in Im pretty sure you can see that its not 100% smooth. In fact, the best way to see if it is completely smooth woudl be to calulate the derivative of it.... Try other interpolation techniques, e.g. spline

Comment: I've zoomed in on the _int graphs and they look perfectly smooth.   I will try spline on my real data - hopefully it fits fine

Comment: Here is the last plot, fitted with the spline interp1:  http://i.imgur.com/z4YuUbV.png

Comment: Good! Interpolation definitely matters! Spline interpolation does use the adjacent points to not only fit the data in the value, but also in the derivative. Thats why it works.

Comment: I really need the derivative to go through the data points... 
With my real data, I don't have the "E points", which is why I'm trying to kind-of reverse engineer it with other data, to first find a method that works

Comment: But it wont. You can not create a method that will generate the exact data. thats impossible. an interpolation its just and educated guess of what the point will be...I guess that you may get better results if you derive and then interpolate that.

Comment: One minute, lemme try that :-)

Comment: Sorry it took so long.

Here it is: http://paste.ofcode.org/3bvLCpNykKDaNGzzzPqSe6g and http://imgur.com/nzwIcp7.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93095/discussion-between-ander-biguri-and-mierzen).